# require() with d3 and d3-3d does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to require() d3 and d3-3d but when I do this it seems to break without error. For example, if I try the following I expect to see the black outline, but nothing shows up. if I change the `require(["d33d", "d3"], function(d33d, d3) {` to `require(["d3"], function(d3) {` then this will work. There are no errors in the console. Yes, I haven't begun to use any d3-3d features yet in this code. Seemingly adding the require for d3-3d introduces a regression.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js",
        d33d: "https://unpkg.com/d3-3d@0.1.2/build/d3-3d.min.js",
     }
 });
 
 require(["d3", "d33d"], function(d3, d33d) {
    var width = 700;
    var height = 400;
    var svg = d3.select("#myChart")
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .style('border', '1px solid black');
 });
```

Comment: Why do you use require? Is there a special reason for this?

I think you should use these libraries with `import` instead like it's mentioned in the docs.